A Variable Font with an Italic axis on MSWord on Mac
I have been strugling to get my font (converted from glyphs using fonttools but that's not so important) to work well in MS Word on Mac. To keep it simple, I have only kept wght between Light(300) and Regular(400), and ital between 0 and 11, with preset styles Light, Regular, Light Italic, (Regular) Italic.
Now, when I install the font on Mac, all looks well in font book, and all looks well in the mac built-in text editor. The trouble is when I select the font in MS Word.
When the font is generated by fonttools, it does not have the STAT table, and in MS-Word I only have Italic listed twice:

I found out that some fonts have a STAT table, so I tried to add one. The result is better but still not OK:

I have been playing with the STAT table and with the fvar table to no avail. I also tried to find a font that works, but I didn't find any with an Italic axis. My STAT table:
    <STAT>
      <Version value="0x00010001"/>
      <DesignAxisRecordSize value="8"/>
      <!-- DesignAxisCount=2 -->
      <DesignAxisRecord>
        <Axis index="0">
          <AxisTag value="wght"/>
          <AxisNameID value="256"/>  <!-- Weight -->
          <AxisOrdering value="0"/>
        </Axis>
        <Axis index="1">
          <AxisTag value="ital"/>
          <AxisNameID value="257"/>  <!-- Italic -->
          <AxisOrdering value="1"/>
        </Axis>
      </DesignAxisRecord>
      <!-- AxisValueCount=4 -->
      <AxisValueArray>
        <AxisValue index="0" Format="1">
          <AxisIndex value="0"/>
          <Flags value="0"/>
          <ValueNameID value="258"/>  <!-- Light -->
          <Value value="300.0"/>
        </AxisValue>
        <AxisValue index="1" Format="3">
          <AxisIndex value="0"/>
          <Flags value="2"/>  <!-- ElidableAxisValueName -->
          <ValueNameID value="260"/>  <!-- Regular -->
          <Value value="400.0"/>
          <LinkedValue value="750.0"/>
        </AxisValue>
        <AxisValue index="2" Format="3">
          <AxisIndex value="1"/>
          <Flags value="2"/>  <!-- ElidableAxisValueName -->
          <ValueNameID value="282"/>  <!-- Roman -->
          <Value value="0.0"/>
          <LinkedValue value="11.0"/>
        </AxisValue>
        <AxisValue index="3" Format="1">
          <AxisIndex value="1"/>
          <Flags value="0"/>
          <ValueNameID value="257"/>  <!-- Italic -->
          <Value value="11.0"/>
        </AxisValue>
      </AxisValueArray>
      <ElidedFallbackNameID value="2"/>  <!-- Regular -->
    </STAT>

How do I modify a variable font with an Italic axis, so that MS Word on Mac displays the preset styles correctly?

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
